# EOF exception while using pexpect for ssh password prompt

Tags: python, windows, ssh, pexpect

So I wrote the following after reading the pexpect docs:

```
import pexpect
from pexpect import popen_spawn
child = popen_spawn.PopenSpawn("ssh -t -t root@server1")
child.expect('password:')
child.sendline('pwd')        # Send the password
```

Now here's the error that I'm getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ssh_exp.py", line 4, in <module>
    child.expect('password:')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pexpect\spawnbase.py", line 315, in expect
    timeout, searchwindowsize, async)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pexpect\spawnbase.py", line 339, in expect_list
    return exp.expect_loop(timeout)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pexpect\expect.py", line 102, in expect_loop
    return self.eof(e)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pexpect\expect.py", line 49, in eof
    raise EOF(msg)
pexpect.exceptions.EOF: End Of File (EOF).
<pexpect.popen_spawn.PopenSpawn object at 0x0000000002BA3F98>
```

I have verified that the connectivity to server1 is proper and ssh does not close without prompting for password. Is there anything I'm missing here?

Comment: how does the password prompt look like?

Comment: The prompt text is `root@server1's password:`

Comment: This seems a common error when using pexpect in Windows. I'm debugging it right now.

Comment: found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

In general, this happens when what you expect ('password'), is not found in the output.

There would be some situations, when the server requested to install public key on your machine and you should expect '(yes/no)?' - like the below output.

he authenticity of host ' ' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is x:xx:35:ae:1a:2e:69:e4:4d:b4:5e:2d:02:xx:f2:ed.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?

Comment: This was not the case: "I have verified that the connectivity to server1 is proper and ssh does not close without prompting for password."